# How to get the Number of ApplicationUser in the AspNetUsers Table in ASP.Net MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Is there any way to get the number of users in the `AspNetUsers` table which is automatically created by the `ASP.Net` `MVC 5`?

In the `ApplicationDbContext` which is created automatically in the `IdentityModels.cs` file when you start a `ASP.Net MVC 5` project, I do not see something like:

```
public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
```

which is a typical way of representing and getting the entries in the database's table for a certain connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your context is using [Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity) (probably v2) which means it inherits from [`IdentityDbContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn468176(v=vs.108).aspx), that is where you will see the [users `DbSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt151757(v=vs.108).aspx#P:Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityDbContext%606.Users). So you should be able to write something like this:

```
var userCount = context.Users.Count();
```

Comment: Found it! It is as you say, thanks! Will accept it when the grace period is over! :)